# Periodicity of algebraic functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I came across this result - An algebraic function cannot be periodic unless it is a constant function. I get the intuition of solving it by writing the function in the form of a polynomial equation, where this function will be one root of the aforementioned equation, and then replace the 'x' in the equation by 'x+T' where T is the period of the function. Then by some further argument, we can simplify things and get to some contradiction that no such T could exist. But I am having difficulty in proving this.

Comment: To begin with, an algebraic function can only have so many roots.

Answer (score 4):

***Identity Theorem-***

A polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ is identically zero if it vanishes for at least $n+1$ distinct values of $x$.

Proof- Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,...\alpha_n$ be the roots of the $n$th degree polynomial $f(x)$. Then,

$$f(x)=a(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)...(x-\alpha_n)$$

Let $\alpha_{n+1}$ be the $n+1$th value for which $f(x)$ vanishes. Then

$$f(\alpha_{n+1})=a(\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha_1)(\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha_2)...(\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha_n)=0$$

$$ \implies a=0\implies f(x)=0$$

Using above result we can say that two polynomials $f(x),g(x)$ of degree $m$ and $n$ respectively (with $m$ less than or equal to $n$) are equal if they have equal values at $n+1$ distinct values of $x$.

Proof- Let $$P(x)=f(x)-g(x)$$

now degree of $P(x)$ is at most $n$ and vanishes for $n+1$ distinct values of $x$. Hence, $P(x)$ is identically zero and thus $f(x)=g(x)$.

**Corollary-**

The only periodic polynomial function is the constant function.

Proof-   Let $$f(0)=c$$

Now, $$f(T)=f(2T)=...=c$$

Hence, the polynomial function $f(x)$ and $g(x)=c$ take equal values at infinitely distinct values of $x$. Hence, they must be identical.

Thus, we have, $$f(x)=C$$ for all periodic polynomial functions $f(x)$.

---